# Export GridView to Excel (not working)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, updatepanel, export-to-excel

I've spent the last two days trying to get some bloody data to export to Excel. After much research I determined that the best and most common way is using `HttpResponse` headers as shown in my code below. After stepping through countless times in debug mode, I have confirmed that the data is in fact there and both filtered and sorted the way I want it. However, it does not download as an Excel file, or do anything at all for that matter.

I suspect this may have something to do with my `UpdatePanel` or perhaps the `ImageButton` not posting back properly, but I'm not sure. What am I doing wrong? Please help me to debug this issue. I will be eternally grateful. Thank you. :)

**Markup**

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="statusUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExportXLS" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10"
        AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="GridView1SDS" DataKeyNames="ID">
    </asp:GridView>
    <span><asp:ImageButton ID="btnExportXLS" runat="server" /></span>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Codebehind**

```vb
Protected Sub ExportToExcel() Handles btnExportXLS.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(SelectCommand, ConnectionString)

    da.Fill(dt)

    Dim gv As New GridView()
    gv.DataSource = dt
    gv.DataBind()

    Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xls")
    Response.Charset = String.Empty

    gv.RenderControl(hw)
    Response.Write(sw.ToString()) 'sw is a valid html table, but no Excel file downloads. :(
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. I'm missing a `Response.Clear` at the beginning.
2. You are calling `GridView.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter)`, hence the page raises an exception that a Server-Control was rendered outside of a Form. Try to execute it in the debugger and i'm fairly sure that you'll see that exception.

You could avoid this exception by overriding [VerifyRenderingInServerForm](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

```
Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control As Control)
    ' Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET '
    ' server control at run time.  '
End Sub
```

See [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1016960.aspx/1?Problem%20with%20GridView%20s%20RenderControl) and [here](http://aspalliance.com/771_CodeSnip_Exporting_GridView_to_Excel).

**Edit**: I've only just seen that you're using an `UpdatePanel`. Make sure that you've created a (Full-)`PostBackTrigger` for that button:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdGridInfo" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ToolTip="export to Excel" ID="BtnExcelExport" ImageUrl="~/images/excel2007logo.png" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnExcelExport" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

But instead of creating a html-table that can be interpreted by excel, i would use a Excel Library like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)(GPL) which i can warmly recommend.

Then it is as easy as this to create  Excel-Files from a DataTable and write it to the Response:

```
Dim pck = New ExcelPackage()
Dim ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet-Name")
ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dt, True, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium1)
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelFileName.xlsx")
Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray())
Response.End()
```

Here is another example: http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample

Comment: Hi again Tim, I've tried it with 1 & 2 as well, but still nothing. I also stepped through in debug and no errors, or perhaps they are being swallowed. This is driving me bonkers. It shouldn't be this difficult. :( Thanks for the tip on the library, I'll give it a try if I still can't get this working, but I really don't want to learn yet another library or plugin if it's avoidable.

Comment: Yes, that's why I posted my markup to show the `UpdatePanel` and mentioned it in my question as well, lol. How do I force a full postback when the button is pressed? I wanted to do that, but no button has the `AutoPostBack` property. :(

Comment: I've showed how to force a full postback for the download button only by using a `PostBackTrigger`. `AutoPostBack` is not needed since a buton(or ImageButton) automatically posts back.

Comment: OH MY WORD!!! That fixed it. It has to be a `PostBackTrigger` vs an `AsyncPostBackTrigger`. CURSE YOU UPDATE PANEL!!! Will you cause no end of trouble for me!! Argghh!!! Thanks so much Tim, you saved me again. ^.~ (everyone, thumbs up this answer; it's sure to help someone else).

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to follow these steps:

**Step 1 (In Design Page)**

SET `EnableEventValidation ="false"` in `"%@ Page"`

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Aroghyam.master" EnableEventValidation ="false" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Search_IncidentStatus.aspx.vb" Inherits="Search_IncidentStatus" %>
```

**Step 2 (In Design Page)**

If there is an update panel then add an *Export* button, which, when clicked will export grid data to Excel format `asp:PostBackTrigger`  (don't put this in `asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger`

```
`<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExportToExcel" />`
```

**Step 3 (In Code)**

Add the following:

```
Public Overloads Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)

    ' no implementation necessary,used just to handle error (just paste this to your       code)
End Sub
```

**Step 4 (In Code)**

Generate the Excel content:

```
'-------------------GETTING THE DATATABLE------------------
Dim searchResultTable as new Datatable = // GET TABLE FROM DATABASE
'----------------------------------------------------------

'-------------------ASSIGNING TABLE TO GRID----------------
GvIncidentStatus.DataSource = SearchResultTable
GvIncidentStatus.DataBind()

'-----------------CODE FOR GENERATION TO EXCEL
Response.Clear()
GvIncidentStatus.AllowPaging = False
Response.Buffer = True
Me.EnableViewState = False
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=MyExcelfile.xls"))
Response.Charset = ""
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
Dim sw As New StringWriter()
Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
GvIncidentStatus.RenderControl(hw)
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
Response.End()
'-----------------
```

Clicking the export button will now download an Excel document.

Comment: ahhh ... STOP SHOUTING! Or in other words: please remove the all caps comments, they are too hard to read. And while you are at editing, please clean up the formatting mess of your code