# Gridview to Excel Issue

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a chunk of code which extracts data from Grid View into excel file. But instead of extracting the grid view data it is copying entire data present in the html view into my excel as below:

[image]

How can I get only my Grid View data into excel?
My excel generation code is below. I don't use Response.End() as it throws ThreadAbortException.

```
protected void btnExcelGenerator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

            GridViewRefurb.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
            Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

}
```

Help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: I would not export HTML but a real excel-file. With `EPPlus` it's very easy, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12222648/284240

Comment: @Tim thanks but in your example it doesn't load from gridview but from a data table. I want the data displayed inside my grid view to reflect in excel. Confused a bit as I have never heard of EPPlus. I could use a help

Comment: But the `GridView` has a `Dat5aSource`. Use that for `LoadFromDataTable` or `LoadFromCollection`.

Comment: EPPlus is an external dll and also there is no "Dim" keyword in c#. It is used in vb. Hence im getting an error where it encounters Dim

Comment: `Dim` is VB.NET since the linked answer answers a VB.NET question. `Dim` is `var`in C#.

Comment: I tried with var but at this point it says error while accessing the cells i.e ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(data, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium1);

Comment: A collection indexer in VB.NET has paranthesis`()`, C# uses square brackets `[]`. So: `ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(data, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium1);` If you want to convert something from VB to C# or vice-versa use http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ Here is another answer of me for C#: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9574414/284240

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68535/discussion-between-user2470766-and-tim-schmelter).

Answer (score 0):

Do some changes

1) ASPX Page : Gridview within Panel

```
     <asp:panel id = "panel_export" runat = "server" >
       <asp:Gridview id = "Gridview" runat = "server">
        </Gridview> 
    </asp:Panel>
```

2) ON Excel Export render panel instead of Gridview

```
        panel_export.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
```